# jquery tokeninput cuts defaultValue after 14 characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using jQuery with tokeninput Plugin.

I initialize it with:

```
$("input#id").tokenInput(url, { defaultValue: "Very Long string 1234567810", ...});
```

After page loading the input box has the value "Very Long string 123". After focus and blur the box, the value becomes "Very Long string 1234567810".

Anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Try changing the input's `size` attribute to accommodate the characters?

Comment: Is not working with the size attribute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution for my self:

After initializing the tokenInput, there are no style-width attribute of the generated input element.

After adding a css width attribute, all text is shown.

```
$("#myid").tokenInput (url, options);
$("#token-input-myid").css({"width": "200px"});
```

Comment: This won't work: Once you start typing, an annoying internal "feature" called resize_input() kicks in and changes input size back to {entered text len} + 30. Look at blushrt's answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer here did not solve the problem for me. I ended up creating new settings field
'resizeInput' with default value true.

You can get the modified plugin  [on my github](https://github.com/smnplk/jquery-tokeninput)

Use it like this:

```
$("#my_input_id").tokenInput("/my_url.json",{ resizeInput: false});
```